# Angular - Observable check if value exists

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a list of users in my database.

```
user1: {name: "John", pet: {name:"Riko", type: "dog"}, married: true, children: [{name: "Marry", relationship: "daughter"}] },
user2: {name: John", married: false}
```

After fetching a user's node I wish to check if that user has certain information. In my case, I want to check if the user has the fields `pet`,`married` and `children`.

If he does, I want to store the user's object with a new attribute inside: `completedQuiz: true`(since he has added the missing information through a quiz).

After implementing the logic from above the result I should obtain is:

```
user1: {name: "John", pet: {name:"Riko", type: "dog"}, married: true, children: [{name: "Marry", relationship: "daughter"}], completedQuiz: true },
user2: {name: John", married: false, completedQuiz: false}
```

`user2` has `completedQuiz: false` since he does not have all `pet`,`married` and `children` nodes while `user1` has `completedQuiz: true` since he does have those fields.

**P.S.** I also want to subscribe to that list so if data is added after fetching, I will still have the most up-to-date `completedQuiz` status for all users.

What would be a good way to implement this?

Comment: Well what have you tried? Please post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: Share some work you have tried. Use the map operator to transform the objects after checking your criteria.

Comment: Since you haven't provided any approach to achieve this - how about you use sql to fetch the data, write a your backend logic for updating a record, a middleware with pipe/map and a frontend displaying the datatable ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have an observable which returns the users from database. You can then transform them using map:

```
users.map( (user) => {
    ...user,
    completedQuiz: user.pet && user.married && user.children
});
```

Comment: `user.children` ?